# Linking two fields from different tables (are relationships required?)

Tags: ms-access

For example, I have two tables.  Employees and Products.

Inside Employees I have the fields: emp_ID, emp_fname, emp_lname, emp_products
Inside Products I have the fields: pro_ID, pro_name, pro_warehouse, pro_employees

Any employee can sell any product.  I want to track which employees sell which products, and which products are sold by which employee.

If I do a lookup wizard in Employees: emp_products and allow multiple selections, and the same thing in Products: pro_employees...then in the Employee: emp_products field I select "Dodge Ram" and "Jeep Rubicon"  I want that employee added to the respective Product record in Products: pro_employees.

Is this even possible, and if so...how do I go about this?  I'm pretty new and I'm having a hard time searching the right words/phrases for this without coming up with relationship support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a table to sit between Employees and Products.  It will contain the `emp_Id` and `pro_id`, though you may discover other columns later. As an employee sells a product insert the corresponding combination of IDs into this table. Remove `emp_products` and `pro_employees` from your model.